# Error trying to show Spanish or French characters with PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdfbox

I´m trying to create a PDF with PDFBOX-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT but I´m having problems and errors.
This is the typical Hello World example with Spanish and French characters:

```
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
    document.addPage(page);
    PDType1Font font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

    PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
    String text = "áÁÀà";
    stream.beginText();
    stream.setFont(font, 12);
    stream.newLineAtOffset(100, 700);
    stream.showText(text);
    stream.endText();
    stream.close();
    document.save("sample.pdf");
    document.close();
```

And I get this error:

```
sep 02, 2015 12:42:43 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font <init>
ADVERTENCIA: Using fallback font ArialMT for base font ZapfDingbats
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This font type only supports 8-bit code points
```

If I load arialuni.ttf font it compiles but only get question marks in the PDF file.

I have tried PDFBOX 1.8 and doesn´t work either.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

After some test I realized that if you change the encoding of the project (at least in Intellij IDEA) and don´t retype the problematic characters in the code, the new encoding doesn´t take effect.

Answer (score 0):

The PDType1Font.XXX are fonts which are provided by the PDF viewers itself which don't support unicode. You should be able to use a TTF font like on: https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/EmbeddedFonts.java

```
PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(document, new File("path/YourFont.ttf"));
```